# jquery typeahead not working in imacros browser

Tags: imacros, typeahead

i'm new here so first a hello to all!

the problem is when i start typing in the field dropdown list is showing up on Record.

But when play, the dropdown list is showing up

My code looks like:

**

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#regularPatientName" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#regularPatientName" CHAR="A"
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#oldpatientDiv>UL>LI>A" BUTTON=0
```

**

the imacros browser does nothing, no errors are reported, just nothing happens when i write a text in the field

i'm using imacros10 with Firefox browser on windows7 (although that has nothing to do with it)

Comment: Try to apply these `EVENT` commands in ‘iMacros’ extension for Firefox.

Comment: I am using EVENT commands but it is not work when play

Comment: It's strange enough. Maybe [the wiki](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVENT) can give some ideas why.